# Draw plot bands between 2 points in x axis - Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have been working with highcharts for a while now. I understand that we can draw plot bands [**like this**](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/plot-bands-and-plot-lines)

I need to get this customized like the one in the chart below, any pointers on how we could do it?

[image]

Comment: you can use a area chart for that plot band

Comment: @strikers, thank you for replying.  A little more information could be helpful. http://www.highcharts.com/demo/area-basic

Comment: Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/5x4xp78s/  You can preprocess your data to automate the calculation of the area series values.

Comment: Or, more like your example:  Or this way: http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/5x4xp78s/3/

Comment: @jlbriggs you have been really helpful.Thank you very much. Can you add your examples and your suggestions as an answer, I am sure it will help a lot of people

Answer (score 0):

You need to use renderer (path with z option, which end shape)

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, on highcharts forum, I got this response: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/arearange-line and 
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/arearange-line/

How relevant would this be? I am trying to get a growth projection using a straight line and fill color below it - its like a combination of threshold and plot band - but a little rotated like this http://jsfiddle.net/roydondsouza/7bzudzvs/

Comment: Both an area series and using the renderer are valid options. I would personally choose to work with an area series, but only because I am more familiar with manipulating that than I am the renderer.

Comment: @jlbriggs Thank you very much, I would be a little more comfortable with a renderer